# How to read from a file char by char in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read from a file, but the only thing I get on working is using getline().

The problem is that reading a whole line doesnt to the job for me.

My input file looks like this:

```
abc 10 20
bbb 10        30
ddd 40 20
```

when the first word in each line should be saved as a string, and both number afterwards as ints.
The delimiter between the "words" in each line can be either a SPACE or a TAB.

So is the only solution is reading char by char? Or is there another solution?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=read+characters+from+a+file+in+c%2B%2B

Comment: And `fscanf` won't work for you?

Comment: How or why doesn't reading the whole line do the job for you? Once you've read the line, you can do whatever you want with it, including separating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposedly you want something like this:

```
std::string s;
int         v0, v1;
while (in >> s >> v0 >> v1) {
    std::cout << "do something with s='" << s << "' v0=" << v0 << " v1=" << v1 << "\n";
}
```

This doesn't make sure that the values are all on one line, however. If you want to arrange for this you probably want to read a line using `std::getline()` and then split this line up as above using an `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Thank you, finally someone who actually recommends streams instead of C functions...

Comment: You aren't really surprised that someone who implemented his [own version of IOStreams](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) (yes, it is fairly out of date but I'm actively working on an update) is recommending the use of IOStreams? ;-)

Comment: I am surprised that no one else does.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getline()` and have a function return each successive character from the string it received from `getline()`.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I agree with @Dietmar's answer -- but I'd probably go a bit further. From the looks of things, each line of input represents some sort of logical record. I'd probably create a class to represent that record type, and provide an overload of `operator>>` for that class:

```
class my_data { 
    std::string name;
    int val1, val2;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, my_data &m) { 
        std::string temp;
        std::getline(is, temp);
        std::istringstream buffer(temp);
        buffer >> m.name >> m.val1 >> m.val2;
        return is;
    }
};
```

You might want to do a little extra logic to propagate a failed conversion in the stringstream out to the istream where you read the raw data.

In any case, with this in place, you can (for example) initialize a vector of objects directly from the stream:

```
std::vector<my_data> whatever(
    (std::istream_iterator<my_data>(some_stream)),
    (std::istream_iterator<my_data>());
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea from @Dietmar of reading with operator>> for each single value is good, but you still have this problem with the endline.

However, you don't have to store the whole line in a temporary string, you can do it streamed and more efficiently with std::istream::ignore():

```
bool read_it(std::istream& in, std::string& s, int& a, int& b)
{
  if (in >> s >> a >> b) // read the values
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // read the newline      
  return in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for.I suppose you want to read a text file and save a string and two ints (at each line) and printing each in a new line.If so try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    int a,b;
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    if(file.is_open() == false)
        {
        cout << "Error: File can't be loaded" << endl;
        exit(1);
        }
    while(1)    
    {
        if(!file)
        break; 
        file >> str;
        file >> a;
        file >> b;
        cout << str << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
    }
    file.close(); // Close the file to prevent memory leaks
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a file char-by-char, while preserving input text formatting, you can use the following:

```
if (in.is_open())
    char c;
    while (in.get(c)) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

where `in` is an input stream of type `std::ifstream`. You can open such a file, like so: `std::ifstream in('myFile.txt');`

If you don't mind formatting and would rather print all in one line, then you can follow Dietmar Kühl's advice.

Answer (score -1):

Use fscanf, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/

```
fscanf(stream, "%s %d %d", &s, &a, &b);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use it like this, though. At least use it like this: `if (fscanf(stream, "%s %d %d", &s, &a, &b) == 3) { ... }`. You **always** want to check the result of input. Also, be aware that this use is still prone to buffer overruns: the string being read is allowed to have arbitrary size but it is unlikely that you have allocated enough space for all definitions of arbitrary.